# <input type="date"> - jQuery catch event clear date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, events

I don't know how to catch the event of clearing the date, when deleting the date by clicking the x. The click event is not useful, because i get the change event.

HTML:

[Date Field with clear x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsNWI.png)

i want to catch the event when clicking the x (see pic).
Any Hints?

Using jQuery v3.2.1 and Bootstrap v3

Comment: Well AFAIK you may implement    `on change` event here to make it work, but i don't think that you can catch the event when X is clicked.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qewyak05/ quick fiddle. Just use the `on change` from jquery.

Comment: Use the `onchange` event and then check if `$(this).val()` is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just listen for the change event. This script should work with or without jQuery and will write to the console when a value is set and when the clear button is clicked:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (!input.value)
    console.log('clear!');

  else
    console.log('value', input.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work if `Clear` is pressed but nothing was entered

Comment: @Dexygen should it? I did say _write to the console when a **value is set** and when the clear button is clicked_ - if no value is set the change event doesn't fire because clearing doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Keith, thats was a good inpiration for my solution.

I'm used jquery for the project, so i needed a solution in jquery.

this js solution solves one problem, but another problem was: if loading the page and deleting the date value by clicking the clear button ("x"), the change event didn't recognized it. the solution:

```
$('.date-input')
    .click(function(e) {
         $(this).focus();
    }
    .change(function(e) {
         var myValue = $(this);
         if (!myValue.val()) {
            // do something when cleared
         } else {
            // do something on changed date
         }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" class="date-input" />
```

Comment: _"I'm used jquery for the project, so i needed a solution in jquery."_ you don't. jQuery is just a load of helpers on top of JS, and you don't _need_ to use it all the time. If you have code that doesn't use jQuery that will still play nice with the code you have that does need it. However, yes - if you wanted to translate my answer into jQuery it would look like this code. You probably don't need the `click` as it should set focus anyway (as will keyboard events).